# unable to connect when cron runs my python script

Tags: cron, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a python script `main.py` , which reads my latest tweet using tweepy. 
I created a shell script looplauncher.sh, which call this python script:

```
cd /
cd home/pi/LCDinterface
sudo python main.py &
cd /
```

If I run `python main.py` or `sh looplauncher.sh` with or without sudo, my program runs fine. I pasted this line into cron: using `sudo crontab -e`

```
*/2 * * * * sleep 60 && sudo sh /home/pi/LCDinterface/looplauncher.sh >/home/pi/logs/loopcronlog 2>&1
```

The python script really does run at every 2 minutes ( I see it from the logs). But I can never get my tweet, If I run main.py manually I always get my tweet.  I tried a lot of combination of sudo/ no sudo, added delay to give time for the connection. But nothing works so far. Can you help me with that? (I am doing this on a Raspberry Pi 3)

I got errors like this , when cron runs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 32, in main
    tweet = getTweet('RaspProject')
  File "/home/pi/LCDinterface/twitterHelper.py", line 20, in getTweet
    print (tweet._json['text'])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Running manually the scripts works fine. (Although I do really have some special hungarian letters in there, like éáőóű

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line before everything else in your crontab:

```
PATH=/usr/bin/:/bin
```

Comment: it did not solve my problem unfortunately, I printed out sys.executable, and it was always /usr/bin/python, but stil I always ended up getting decode errors, when running from cron. Anyway I switched to python3 made some modfications and now everything works. Thanks for your help.